# Google Maps API: Prevent dragging into a grey area

Tags: google-maps

I am using Google Maps API (v3) to render a world map. When I zoom all the way out (to zoom level 1) and start dragging the canvas, I am able to move out of the map boundaries, and the area outside shows up in grey color. I want to prevent the user from dragging the map outside the boundaries of the world map. How do I do that?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You could set minZoom and maxZoom to ensure that the available zoom levels are within your boundaries, hope that helps?

Comment: Adding a zoom level does not prevent the user from dragging the map so that the gray area is visible.

Comment: That's is just for zooming, not for dragging map.

Comment: this does not prevent the user from dragging to the grey area

Answer (score 2):

Google Maps api has the corresponding option:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapRestriction.latLngBounds. Need to add something like:

```
restriction: {
  latLngBounds: { north: 85, south: -85, west: -180, east: 180 }
}
```

to the initial options of the map.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var map;
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0,0);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 1,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions); 
   map.addListener( 'drag', function() { handle(); });
   //map.addListener( 'zoom_changed', function() { handle(); });
}

function handle(){
  var proj = map.getProjection();
  var bounds = map.getBounds();
  var sLat = map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat();
  var nLat = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat();
  if (sLat < -85 || nLat > 85) {
   // alert('Gray area visible');
   map.setOptions({
     zoom: 1,
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(
                  0 , // set Latitude for center of map here
                  0) // set Langitude for center of map here
              });         
   //Map.fitBounds(boundsNew); 
   // Or Define bound that u want show
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps</title>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()" >
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px;height:500px;"></div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Good job copy+pasting code that doesn't work on multiple levels (unused variables, missing variables, commented out code) without even a description. Also good job to the people upvoting an unhelpful and low quality answer.

Comment: This solution does not event work properly, still got three upvotes :O

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice your comment earlier @Kunal, 
The 'Run code snippet' button shows the google map and immediately opens up a modal saying 'This page can't load Google Maps correctly'

Comment: @towkir This is new to Google Maps API. As stated here https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/understanding-cost-of-use

All Google Maps Platform API requests must include an API key; we no longer support keyless access.
You’ll need to enable billing on each of your projects.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old, but I was looking for an answer and found this post.

I think my answer could be an improvement to the accepted one.

Instead of sending the user back to an arbitrary center, move the map back to the edge of the grey area.

```
var map;
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0,0);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 1,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);    
      map.addListener( 'drag', function() { handle(); });
      //map.addListener( 'zoom_changed', function() { handle(); });
}

function handle(){
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    var center = map.getCenter();
    var sLat   = bounds.getSouthWest().lat();
    var nLat   = bounds.getNorthEast().lat();
    var cLat   = center.lat();
    var cLng   = center.lng();
    if (sLat < -85) {
        map.setOptions({
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(
                cLat + ((sLat + 85) * -1),
                cLng
            )
        )};
    }
    if (nLat > 85) {
        map.setOptions({
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(
                cLat - nLat + 85,
                cLng
            )
        )};
    }
}
```

Hope this could help someone.